# Can a Warlock pact weapon have a sheath as part of its form?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, improvised-weaponry

Can a Warlock pact weapon have a sheath as part of its form? If so could it be used as a weapon? Asking because I wanted a sword cane with the sheath as part of the pact weapon.

Comment: If the GM says no because it's 'two items', consider choosing [a gun cane](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqwZODv9TTAhUKwFQKHeThBMYQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.guns.com%2F2017%2F04%2F29%2Fcane-guns%2F&psig=AFQjCNFM8x7a3ItTYO_4U2LxWo_gu31zLQ&ust=1493927283542437) instead (be sure to include a bayonette or whack someone with it before hand so it's clear that it's melee!).

Answer (score 4):

The Pact of the Blade states

> You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it (see chapter 5 for weapon options)

And in Chapter 5, the weapon options are listed in page 149. A sheath or scabbard is not listed there, unfortunately. So you cannot *make* a Pact Weapon that is a sheath, and technically, you can't make a sheathed weapon as well, since it isn't listed.

However, it also states:

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon

So if you hold one magic weapon that has a sheath as part of its form (a sword cane, as you say) and transform it into your pact weapon, then it can be, sheath and all.

But note that there is no out-of-the-box item that is like this, so your DM will have to custom make it for you. The sheath has to be explicitly stated to be an integral part of the single magic item called a "sword cane" such that both the sword and sheath are considered one item, two parts of a whole.

Comment: The weapon is the weapon, the sheath is the sheath - if you made a magic sheathed weapon your pact weapon the weapon would go into the place where pact weapons live but the sheath would stay here Shirley?

Comment: @DaleM I agree. But the DM could make a custom magic item in which the sheath is part of the magic weapon, and so it would work in that case (I specifically called out that the sheath is part of the magic weapon's form -- as does the querent). As you say, typical magic weapons which are only the blades, even if they were sheathed, would not have those sheaths be included as part of the pact weapon.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're trying to get two pact weapons instead of one, and you may suspect correctly this is not the Rules as Written or Intended.

> You can use your action to create **a** pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it (see chapter 5 for weapon options).

Sheaths and/or sword canes are a weapon, but two items.  The sheath is not a weapon, and thus not created. The sword cane is two weapons which do not fit the rules, as they are written.  This can be confirmed in that it references to chapter 5 weapon options, which does not list sword canes or sheaths as weapons.